# Synchronous and asynchrous strategy

Tags: mule

I want to run one thread at a time in my mule flow. And also i want to take input only one by one, i.e.,for first input once I completed with the flow, only then Mule flow picks the second input. Which strategy should I use??

If I used synchronous strategy, and we have two or more than two files in a folder looking by Mule Flow, it picks all the input at a time.
And if i use asynchronous strategy and 1 thread at a time, then I am not able to complete the full flow before taking any other input.

```
     <flow name="Catalog_command_Execution" doc:name="Catalog_command_Execution" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="${inputCAT.path}" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File" doc:name="Catalog File"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="File Mapping"/>
    <custom-transformer class="com.tcs.sdm.kcm.cmdExecution.CmdCAT" doc:name="CAT cmd Execution"/>
    <logger message="******************Entered file #[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]  for command execution has been Processed*********" level="INFO" category="Audit_LogCAT" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <logger message="*******************************Entered Catalog file for command execution is having error: #[exception.causeException]****************" level="INFO" category="Audit_LOgCAT" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>

       <flow name="CatalogueFlow_AB" doc:name="CatalogueFlow_AB" processingStrategy="allowOneThread">
    <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="${wmq.queue.nameCT_AB}" doc:name="WMQ" connector-ref="WMQ"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="File Mapping"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="CAT Logger" category="Audit_LogCAT" message="******************Entered Catalogue SOAP File with Province Name AB is Processed from queue*********"/>
    <custom-transformer class="com.tcs.sdm.kcm.catalog.ServiceController_AB" doc:name="Java"/>
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="CAT Exception Logger" category="Audit_LogCAT" message="*******************************Entered Catalogue SOAP File with Province Name AB is having error: #[exception.causeException]****************"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Comment: Post your config file for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

From the kind of scenario you are looking for processing one file after another Mule Synchronous processing strategy should serve the purpose.

If you see Mule picking up more than one file then the flow needs to be looked at as to why this is happening.

Update:

The processing strategy on your flow for WMQ inbound is not synchronous. Then it should work as expected.

```
<flow name="CatalogueFlow_AB" doc:name="CatalogueFlow_AB" processingStrategy="synchronous">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mule Synchronous processing strategy is working if i used file inbound endpoint. But if I am using WMQ inbopund endpoint, it is not working. If 6 message are there in queue then all the messages are fetched by flow at once if i used synchronous strategy

Comment: Updated my answer as per your config.

Comment: No. If i use synchronous, then  it is not working. If 6 message are there in queue then all the messages are fetched by flow at once if i used synchronous strategy. to avoid this, I am using queued asynchronous strategy with 1 thread. But this is also not fulfilling my requirement. Please suggest me the some solution

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but have you tried setting the WMQ consumer count to 1?
Flow can be synchronous but that doesn't mean the inbound connector will work in a synchronous manner. For file based connector you can set dispatcher to be non-threaded and for WMQ you should try to make consumers to 1.